# Access and control Media Player created in service from activity

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

Basing on this example: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-android-media-style-notifications-with-media-session-controls/165

I've created a service which playing audio stream from URL with control buttons in notification - I can pause, resume and turn off streaming (by stopping service).

But how can I control this from activity, just like from notification? Of course I can send intents with proper action, but what I want is (for example):

I have opened activity from where I start service, music is playing and then I pull down a notification drawer, kicked pause for example, music is paused but activity is not aware about this

So there is my question - is there any possibility to access running Media Session or something like that from activity and control it just like from notification?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your activity to your service, then add activity as listener to the player, and every time you start, pause ...etc report to your listener (activity). You will need to create your Interface to report such details to whoever wants to track the player's events.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the new MediaSession compat libraries in the android support libraries found here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/index.html

They simplify the process of creating media controllers and establishing the transport control channels for wiring user interface components to media control service classes.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make this valuable contribution :).